# 2-Sided "book" scanning vs. 2-Sided "tablet" scanning?

Tags: scanner, scanning, document-scanning

HP Scanners with Auto Document Feeders (ADF) offer **"2-sided (book)"** scanning and **"2-sided (tablet)"** scanning.

There is no documentation to explain the difference, and searching the internet comes up nil.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard the terminology "tablet" regarding scanning before, but I'm pretty sure it's referencing how the pages turn.  Most scanners I've seen refer to it as "Long edge" or "Short edge", see this helpful diagram:
[image: Scanning diagram]
[FAQ article from Brother website](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/65779/%7E/how-do-i-change-the-scan-settings-to-duplex-%28-double-side%29-scanning-%28home-mode%29%3F)

**Update 2021**

[Sharp](https://business.sharpusa.com/portals/0/downloads/Manuals/MX-6240N-7040N/contents/04-030.htm) says that Booklet is long-side, Tablet is short-side:
[image: Booklet vs Tablet scanning diagram]

Comment: okay.. so which is which??

Comment: @vhflat Updated answer to show which is which.